# Socket.io chat app sends multiple messages with different usernames

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

I know it sounds ridiculous but believe me guys

The chat app that I am making with socket.io has a problem that first when all the users log in it displays the log in message and also after that when anybody posts a message it displays the message but multiple times with all the usernames active in the chat room even if anyone hasn't posted the message,

I am a newbie to node.js & socket.io btw,

Sevrer.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);
const port = 80;
const path = require('path');


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// Now let's move to the socket io part

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('new-user', (username) => {
        //users[socket.id] = username;
        console.log(`${username} just connected to the server!`);
        io.emit('connected-user', username)
        socket.emit('user-connected',username)
        // console.log("A new user just connected!");
    })


    socket.on('senders-name',(username) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('name',username);
        //socket.removeAllListeners('senders-name',username);
    })

       socket.on('send message',(chat) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('the-msg',chat);
        /*socket.on('senders-name',(username) => {
            socket.broadcast.emit('name',username);
        })*/
         console.log(`Sender sent this message : ${chat}`);
    })

    socket.on('send-time',(time) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('time',time);
        console.log(time);
    })

    socket.on('send-date',(date) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('date',date);
        console.log(date);
    })


    socket.on('disconnect',(username) => {
        //io.emit('disconnected-user',users[socket.id]);
    //  users[socket.id] = username;
        socket.broadcast.emit('user-disconnect',username);
        io.emit('user-disconnect',username);
        console.log(`${username} just left!`);
        //delete users[socket.id];
    })
})



server.listen(port, () => {
    //console.log(`Server is listening at the https://localhost:${port}/`);
    console.log(`Server is listening at the https://localhost/`);
});
```

Script.js

```
const socket = io();

const sendBtn = document.getElementById("send");
const form = document.getElementById("forms");
const messageInput = document.getElementById("msgs");

const chatWindow = document.getElementById("chat-window");

const joinBtn = document.getElementById("join");
const refreshBtn = document.getElementById("ref");
const usernameInput = document.getElementById("username");
const bg = document.getElementById("bg");
const userForms = document.getElementById("user-form");

var date = new Date();
var current_date = date.getDate()+"/"+(date.getMonth() + 1)+'/'+date.getFullYear();
var current_time = date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes();


joinBtn.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(usernameInput.value === ''|usernameInput.value == null){
        alert("An username is required before entering the chat!");
    }
    else{
        bg.style.opacity = '0';
        bg.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        // Now lets obtain the user field's value
        const val = usernameInput.value;
        socket.emit('new-user',val);
        socket.emit('user-left',val)
    }
});

userForms.addEventListener('submit',(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
})

/*usernameInput.addEventListener('keydown',(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(keyCode = 13){
        if(usernameInput.value === ''|usernameInput.value == null){
            alert("An username is required before entering the chat!");
        }
        else{
            bg.style.opacity = '0';
            bg.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
            // Now lets obtain the user field's value
            const val = usernameInput.value;
            socket.emit('new-user',val);
            socket.emit('user-left',val)
            socket.emit('senders-name',usernameInput.value);
        }
    }
})*/

document.addEventListener("close",(e) => {
    const val = usernameInput.value;
    socket.emit('user-left',val);
})

socket.on('connected-user', (username) =>{
    const parentContainer = document.createElement('div');
    parentContainer.className = 'join-info';
    chatWindow.appendChild(parentContainer);

    const user = document.createElement('p');
    user.className = 'join';
    user.innerText = `${username} joined the Chat!`;
    parentContainer.appendChild(user);
});

socket.on('user-left', (username) => {
    const parentContainer = document.createElement('div');
    parentContainer.className = 'join-info';
    chatWindow.appendChild(parentContainer);

    const user = document.createElement('p');
    user.className = 'join';
    user.innerText = `${username} left the Chat!`;
    parentContainer.appendChild(user);
})

sendBtn.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
    //e.preventDefault();
    if(messageInput.value === ''|messageInput.value == null){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("First you need to type then click on send!");
    }
})

form.addEventListener("submit",(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(messageInput.value){
        //socket.emit('send message',messageInput.value);
        socket.emit('send-time', current_time);
       // socket.emit('senders-name',usernameInput.value);
        //socket.emit('send-date', current_date);

        const parent = document.createElement('div');
        parent.className = 'parent';
        chatWindow.appendChild(parent);
    
        const chatMsg = document.createElement('div');
        chatMsg.className = 'chat-msg';
        parent.appendChild(chatMsg);
    
        const msgInfo = document.createElement('div');
        msgInfo.className = 'info';
        chatMsg.appendChild(msgInfo);
    
        const time = document.createElement('p');
        time.className = 'time';
        time.innerText = current_time;
        msgInfo.appendChild(time);
    
        const userName = document.createElement('p');
        userName.className = 'time';
        userName.innerText = usernameInput.value;
        msgInfo.appendChild(userName);
    
        const content = document.createElement('div');
        content.className = 'content';
        chatMsg.appendChild(content);
    
        const msg = document.createElement('p');
        msg.className = 'msg';
        msg.innerText = messageInput.value;
        content.appendChild(msg);
    
        messageInput.value = '';
    }
})

socket.on('name',username =>{
    socket.on('the-msg',chat => {
        const parent = document.createElement('div');
        parent.className = 'parent1';
        chatWindow.appendChild(parent);
    
        const chatMsg = document.createElement('div');
        chatMsg.className = 'chat-msg1';
        parent.appendChild(chatMsg);
    
        const msgInfo = document.createElement('div');
        msgInfo.className = 'info1';
        chatMsg.appendChild(msgInfo);
    
        const userName = document.createElement('p');
        userName.className = 'time1';
    
        userName.innerText = username;
        msgInfo.appendChild(userName);
        const time = document.createElement('p');
        time.className = 'time1';
        time.innerText = current_time;
        msgInfo.appendChild(time);
    
        const content = document.createElement('div');
        content.className = 'content1';
        chatMsg.appendChild(content);
    
        const msg = document.createElement('p');
        msg.className = 'msg1';
        msg.innerText = chat;
        content.appendChild(msg);
    
        messageInput.value = '';
    })
})

function showUser(username){
    const parentContainer = document.createElement('div');
    parentContainer.className = 'join-info';
    chatWindow.appendChild(parentContainer);

    const user = document.createElement('p');
    user.className = 'join';
    user.innerText = `${username} joined the Chat!`;
    parentContainer.appendChild(user);
    
}

function appendMessage(message){
    const parent = document.createElement('div');
    parent.className = 'parent';
    chatWindow.appendChild(parent);

    const chatMsg = document.createElement('div');
    chatMsg.className = 'chat-msg';
    parent.appendChild(chatMsg);

    const msgInfo = document.createElement('div');
    msgInfo.className = 'info';
    chatMsg.appendChild(msgInfo);

    const time = document.createElement('p');
    time.className = 'time';
    //time.innerText = Date();
    msgInfo.appendChild(time);

    const userName = document.createElement('p');
    userName.className = 'time';
    userName.innerText = message;
    msgInfo.appendChild(userName);

    const content = document.createElement('div');
    content.className = 'content';
    chatMsg.appendChild(content);

    const msg = document.createElement('p');
    msg.className = 'msg';
    msg.innerText = message;
    content.appendChild(msg);

    messageInput.value = '';
}
```

styles.css

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    scroll-padding-top: .5rem;
}
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgb(30,30,30);
    font-family: system-ui,sans-serif;
}
button{
    outline: none;
}
.chat-container{
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    padding: .2rem .3rem;
    border-radius: .3rem;
    height: 530px;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,purple,74%,rgb(0, 81, 255));
}
.msgs-input{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0rem .3rem .2rem .5rem;
}
#forms{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
.msgs{
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    transition: all .3s;
    border-top-left-radius: .3rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: .3rem;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.msgs:hover{
    background: #dedede;
}
.msgs:focus{
    box-shadow: 0 0px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
.send{
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    border-top-right-radius: .3rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .3rem;
    width: 55px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s;
    background: hsl(160, 84%, 31%);
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
}
.send > span {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    pointer-events: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: rippleffect 1s linear infinite;
  }
@keyframes rippleffect {
    0% {
      height: 0;
      width: 0;
    }
    100% {
      height: 500px;
      width: 500px;
    }
  }

.send:hover{
    background: hsl(160,84%,26%);
    box-shadow: 0 0px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
.send:active{
    scale: .98;
}
.chats{
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background: #2a2d2e;
    border-radius: .3rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding: .3rem 1rem 2rem 1rem;
    overflow: auto;
}
.default{
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 60vh;
}
.chat-header{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    top: 0;
    padding: .3rem 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}
.icon{
    border:none;
    width: fit-content;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.chat-msg1{
    background: #eee;
    padding: .3rem .5rem;
    border-radius: .3rem;
    width: 80%;
    transition: all .2s;
    cursor: default;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
.info1{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.content1{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
.chat-msg{
    background: hsl(160, 93%, 36%);
    padding: .3rem .5rem;
    border-radius: .3rem;
    width: 80%;
    cursor: default;
    transition: all .2s;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
.info{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.content{
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
.content,.content1{
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    padding: .5rem;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
.content1{
    display: flex;
    border: none;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: right;
}
.msg{
    width: 100%;
}
.chat-msg1:hover{
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 83%);
}
.chat-msg:hover{
    background: hsl(160, 93%, 31%);
}
.parent{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: end;
    border-radius: .3rem;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    padding: .3rem 0rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
.parent1{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: start;
    border-radius: .3rem;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    padding: .3rem 0rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
.chat-msg1,.chat-msg{
    animation: pop 1s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes pop {
    from{
        scale: 0;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to{
        scale: 1;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.join-info{
    color: #fff;
    background: #4b4d4e;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    box-shadow: none;
    cursor: default;
    transition: all .3s;
    padding: .5rem .5rem;
    border-radius: .3rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
.join-info:hover{
    background: hsl(200, 2%, 27%);
}
#forms{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.bg{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.6),rgba(0,0,0,.75));
    color: #fff;
    width: 220px;
    padding: .5rem 1rem 1.5rem 1rem;
    border-radius: .3rem;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    height: fit-content;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;
}
.bg{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
.prompt{
    background: #2a2d2e;
    color: #fff;
    width: 220px;
    padding: .5rem 1rem 1.5rem 1rem;
    border-radius: .3rem;

    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    height: fit-content;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;
}
.input-field{
    width: 100%;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.username{
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .6rem 1rem .6rem .5rem;
    font-size: .9rem;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .3rem;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.username:hover{
    background: #dedede;
}
.username:focus{
    box-shadow: 0 0px 20px 0 rgba(90, 106, 143, 0.6);
}
.btns{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.done,.ref{
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    transition: all .2s;
    font-size: .9rem;
    border: none;
    background: #0385b1;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: .3rem;
}
.done:hover,.ref:hover{
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
.done:active,.ref:active{
    scale: .9;
}
#user-form{
    width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .chat-container{
        width: 95%;
    }
}
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Node js Chat application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f3220d5256.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bg" class="bg">
        <div class="prompt">
            <div class="txt">
                <p>
                    Please type your name here before entering the Chat
                </p>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <form id="user-form">
                    <input type="text" id="username" class="username" placeholder="Type Your Name here..." />
                    <br>
                    <div class="btns">
                        <button class="ref" type="reset" id="ref">Refresh</button>
                        <button class="done" type="submit" id="join">Join</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="chat-container">
        <div class="chat-header">
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="header">
                <h3>
                    Blaze Chat Application
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="status">
                <p id="online">
                    Active
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chats"  id="chat-window">
            <!--<div class="default">
                <p>
                    No Messages Yet
                </p>
            </div>-->
            <div class="parent1">
                <div class="chat-msg1">
                    <div class="info1">
                        <p id="name1" class="name1">
                            Inferno (Bot)
                        </p>
                        <p id="time1" class="time1">
                            17:05
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content1">
                        <p id="msg1">
                            Hello everyone! Welcome to the node js chatting application. Please don't misuse this application
                             for anything 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--<div class="parent">
                <div class="chat-msg">
                    <div class="info">
                        <p id="time" class="time">
                            17:07
                        </p>
                        <p id="name" class="name">
                            BlazeInferno64
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <p id="msg" class="msg">
                            Sure! I would keep a check on that in my server. Btw, this application is made on a pure node js based
                             server
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="join-info">
                <p id="join" class="join">
                    BlazeInferno64 left the Chat!
                </p>
            </div>-->

        </div>
        <div class="msgs-input">
            <form id="forms">
                <input type="text" class="msgs" name="messages" id="msgs" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
                <button type="submit" id="send" class="send">
                    <i class="fa fa-send"></i> 
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script defer src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Server.js:

```
const app = express();
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);
const port = 80;
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('new-user', (username) => {
    console.log(`${username} just connected to the server!`);
    socket.broadcast.emit('user-connected', username);
  });

  socket.on('senders-name', (username) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('name', username);
  });

  socket.on('send message', (chat) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('the-msg', chat);
    console.log(`Sender sent this message: ${chat}`);
  });

  socket.on('send-time', (time) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('time', time);
    console.log(time);
  });

  socket.on('send-date', (date) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('date', date);
    console.log(date);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('A user disconnected');
  });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening at https://localhost/`);
});
```

Script.js:

```
const sendBtn = document.getElementById('send');
const form = document.getElementById('forms');
const messageInput = document.getElementById('msgs');
const chatWindow = document.getElementById('chat-window');
const joinBtn = document.getElementById('join');
const usernameInput = document.getElementById('username');

joinBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (usernameInput.value === '' || usernameInput.value == null) {
    alert('An username is required before entering the chat!');
  } else {
    const val = usernameInput.value;
    socket.emit('new-user', val);
    socket.emit('senders-name', val);
    usernameInput.disabled = true;
    joinBtn.disabled = true;
  }
});

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (messageInput.value) {
    const parent = document.createElement('div');
    parent.className = 'parent';
    chatWindow.appendChild(parent);

    const chatMsg = document.createElement('div');
    chatMsg.className = 'chat-msg';
    parent.appendChild(chatMsg);

    const msgInfo = document.createElement('div');
    msgInfo.className = 'info';
    chatMsg.appendChild(msgInfo);

    const time = document.createElement('p');
    time.className = 'time';
    time.innerText = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    msgInfo.appendChild(time);

    const userName = document.createElement('p');
    userName.className = 'time';
    userName.innerText = usernameInput.value;
    msgInfo.appendChild(userName);

    const content = document.createElement('div');
    content.className = 'content';
    chatMsg.appendChild(content);

    const msg = document.createElement('p');
    msg.className = 'msg';
    msg.innerText = messageInput.value;
    content.appendChild(msg);

    socket.emit('send message', messageInput.value);

    messageInput.value = '';
  }
});

socket.on('name', (username) => {
  socket.on('the-msg', (chat) => {
    const parent = document.createElement('div');
    parent.className = 'parent1';
    chatWindow.appendChild(parent);

    const chatMsg = document.createElement('div');
    chatMsg.className = 'chat-msg1';
    parent.appendChild(chatMsg);

    const msgInfo = document.createElement('div');
    msgInfo.className = 'info1';
    chatMsg.appendChild(msgInfo);

    const userName = document.createElement('p');
    userName.className = 'time1';
    userName.innerText = username;
    msgInfo.appendChild(userName);

    const time = document.createElement('p');
    time.className = 'time1';
    time.innerText = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    msgInfo.appendChild(time);

    const content = document.createElement('div');
    content.className = 'content1';
    chatMsg.appendChild(content);

    const msg = document.createElement('p');
    msg.className = 'msg1';
    msg.innerText = chat;
    content.appendChild(msg);

    messageInput.value = '';
  });
});
```

**Please replace your existing code with the provided code and test your chat application again.**

Comment: First of all it shows express() is not defined and secondly it doesn't join me in when I clicked join, btw how do I fix that?